# Laravel 4.1, Both Observer and EventHandler Wont Work on Eloquent Model

Tags: php, laravel, event-handling, laravel-4, observers

Summary: I have a model that I want to observe or Listen, but even after seeing response; nothing happens related to observers / event handles. (Db is ok too)

Sntax errors are recognized within all those files, wrong class names breaks service provider but log doesn't work inside observer and event handler.

Basic Representation of application structure logic:

### Model

```
<?php namespace Foo;
    class Bar extends EloquentModel{...}
```

### BazServiceProvider

```
<?php namespace FooBar;

    use Foo\Bar;
    use ...;

    class BazServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{

        public function register()
        {
            ...    
            Bar::observe(new BarObserver);
            //Or
            Event::subscribe(new BarEventHandler);  
        }
    }
```

### Observer

```
<?php namespace FooBar\Qux;

    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

    class BarObserver{

        public function saved($model) // as well as others
        {
            Log::info("Lorem ipsum");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Observers goes to boot function in service provider. Not register.

*By zenry from forumsarchive.laravel.io*